# JSON on Django template

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x, django-templates

While making a website, I ran into a problem. I am sending a JSON data from *views.py* to my template to print each attribute value from JSON data, but the data showing is empty.

```
data = {
    "philip": {"age": 20, "salary": 10000},
    "jerry": {"age": 27, "salary": 30000}
}    

names = ["philip", "jerry"]

return render(request, 'index.html', {'data': data, 'names': names})
```

I'm storing the names from JSON data in a list and sending both data and names to template.

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    {% for name in names %}
        {{ data.name }}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I want to get values associated with each name.

Comment: That won't work, Django will always interpet `name` as being the literal key "name".

Comment: Got it, @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just directly iterate over `data` as below:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    {% for person, data in data.items %}
        {{ person }} - {{ data }} <br>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

As iterate over `key` and `value` in `dictionary.items()` in python the same way you can follow in template too.

So now you don't need to pass additional list of names to context.