# How to render json to html?

Tags: python, json, django

I've JSON file:

```
[
{
"key1": "value1",
"key2": "value2"
},
{
"key3": "value3",
"key4": "value4"
}]
```

Output should be: `<h1>value1</h1><p>value2</p><h1>value3</h1><p>value4</p>`

I'm trying like that:

```
import json
with open('file.json') as f:
data = json.load(f)

for key in data:
    for k, v in key.items():
       print(k.replace(k, '<h1>') + v + (k.replace(k, '</h1>')))
```

But it's horrible and stupid :(

Also, I have another JSON file:

```
[
   {
"h1": "value1",
"div": "value2"
  }
]
```

Output should be:

```
<h1>value1</h1><div>value2</div>
```

My solution:

```
with open('file2.json') as f:
data = json.load(f)

for key in data:
    for k, v in key.items():
        print(f"<{k}>" + v + f"</{k}>")
```

This one is work, it's possible to make it better?

**And the last one:** 
If JSON have a list,  each element it's has should be `<ul>` tag, and each `<ul>` element should contain `<li>` element:

JSON:

```
[
{
"h1": "value1",
"div": "value2"
},
{
"h1": "value3",
"div": "value4"
}]
```

Output should be: `<ul><li><h1>value1</h1><div>value2</div></li><li><h1>value1</h1><div>value2</div></li></ul>`

**How can i solve these task?** **Please give me some advice which way i can dig it. With Python or Django**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may actually be interested in looking at Django Template. An use with JSON can be found
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49084214/json-on-django-template)

I am not sure if you can use it for the third one though. But in plain Python, something like:

```
html = '<ul>'
for list_item in items:
    html += '<li>'
    for tag, value in list_items.items():
        html += '<{}>{}</{}>'.format(tag, value, tag)
    html += '</li>'
html += '</ul>'
```